# Editing flagged posts

Tags: support

What happens in the following scenario?
I flag a post because (lets say) it's not an answer.
The OP edits the post and adds some valid data.
I see the edit before a moderator can see and validate/invalidate my flag.
I realize that there is no need for the flag anymore.

**(How) can I retract my flag?** because I realize there is no need to bother the moderator with this.

(this really happened today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moderators can see the edit history. I wouldn't bother trying to notify, but if you felt very strongly about it, go ahead and leave a comment on the thread or message them directly.

Comment: Seams reasonable. I'm waiting for a confirmation from one of the moderators then I will accept this answer.

Comment: Since there is no moderator opinion so far, I guess I can go with this.

Comment: Message me next time. Either on twitter or skype (id: boy-named-sue).